# Symfony 6 Routing Translation

Tags: symfony, routes, internationalization, translation

Hi guys I didn't find in documentation and neither [jmsi18nroutingbundle](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSI18nRoutingBundle) seem to be updated for symfony 6 routing i18n, how can I apply this ?

Error I get with jmsi18nroutingbundle on symfony 6

```
Compile Error: Declaration of JMS\I18nRoutingBundle\JMSI18nRoutingBundle::getContainerExtension() must be compatible with Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle::getContainerExtension(): ?Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Extension\ExtensionInterface
```

Also do I need to set `{_locale}` parameter in every route?

Comment: JMSI18nRoutingBundle::getContainerExtension() return not the ExtensionInterface. Check GitHub to see how long ago the last commits were. I guess that Symfony 6 is not supported. The require-dev also specifies: "symfony/symfony": "^4.4|^5.0".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [Localized Routes (i18n)](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#localized-routes-i18n)? Here are examples of the `#Route` attribute and `@Route` annotation:

```php
#[Route(path: [
    'en' => '/about-us',
    'de' => '/uber',
    'nl' => '/over-ons'
], name: 'app.about_us')]
```

```php
/**
 * @Route(
 *     {
 *         "en": "/about-us",
 *         "de": "/uber",
 *         "nl": "/over-ons"
 *     },
 *     name="app.about_us"
 * )
 */
```

You can access these URLs in your application then:

- `https://lorem.ipsum/about-us`
- `https://lorem.ipsum/uber`
- `https://lorem.ipsum/over-ons`